# Simulate simple stack function

Tags: c, stack

I am still learning the C language. I have a problem to simulate a simple stack function, such as push, pop and so on. I found that the `date` and `next` are not initialized in the PTAIL. At that time, the program end. Is that counting as a memory leak?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
typedef struct Node{
    int date;
    struct Node * next;
}Node,*PNode;

typedef struct Stack{
    PNode pHead;
    PNode pTail;
}Stack;

void init(Stack *pS){  
    PNode n=(PNode)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    pS->pHead=n;
    pS->pTail=n;
    n->next=NULL;
}

void push(Stack *pS,int val){ 
    PNode p=(PNode)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->date=val;
    p->next=pS->pHead;
    pS->pHead=p;
}

void travel(Stack *pS){ 
    PNode p=pS->pHead;
    while(p->next){  
        printf("%d ",p->date);
        p=p->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void){

    Stack s;
    init(&s);  
    push(&s,1);
    travel(&s); 

    push(&s,1);
    travel(&s); 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debug your code for easier life, for everyone.

Comment: Why do you create one node on `init`? Why not simply set `pHead` and `pTail` to `NULL` to mark stack as empty?

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: Hi @ᴍarounᴍaroun hmmm, pardon me my c skill is so so, the thing is I have debugged and then find the `next` and `date` are not initialized.

Comment: Hi, @unwind , Thanks, I have seen your post, but i am using c++ compiler now and I have to cast in order to pass the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocate unnecessary node on `init`. What is more, you do not initialize `date` member of it. Remove the node creation:

```
void init(Stack *pS) {  
    pS->pHead = NULL;
    pS->pTail = NULL;
}
```

Casting is unnecessary on `push`.

```
PNode p = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

Your `travel` function is checking for `p->next` even if `p` can be `NULL`. Change the `while` test:

```
void travel(Stack *pS) { 
    PNode p = pS->pHead;
    while(p) {  
        printf("%d ", p->date);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Hi, @user694733 , I don't know why but if i change to "PNode p = malloc(sizeof(Node));" will give me error: a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "PNode"

Comment: Are you using C++ compiler to compile C?

Comment: yes @user694733 , how do you know it. Is that the problem? I thought it is compatible before.

Comment: You can compile *some* C code with C++ compiler, but languages are sightly different (C++ has more strict type checing in this case). Using C++ compiler is not recommended if C compiler is available.

Comment: Hi, @user694733 , i change the file to .c in visual studio(version 2012) but still see same error. I think I need to install a new IDE for C.

Comment: I haven't used Visual Studio, but I *think* there should be a support for C too. Maybe it is some kind of project setting?

Comment: @user3164230 If you just want to test this code, you can just add that cast to malloc and use C++ compiler. Just be aware that you might run into language differences sometimes.

Comment: I get the value 1 and 11 as before, but I get a message from the compiler said  that  "FMUD.exe has triggered a breakpoint ".

Comment: @user3164230 That would seem like a message from the debugger. You may have added breakpoint at some line. Just remove it. I can't help more with that as I am not familiar with VS.

Comment: I checked the code but there is no breakpoints there, but very appreciate your response.

Comment: Hi @user694733, I delete free() function at the last line and then the program comes no message.

Answer (score 1):

Every `malloc` should be paired with a `free()`. You didn't write/show your `pop()` function, but that's the place. If a memory buffer/object is not freed then it's a memory leak.

You allocated an empty first item in `Init()`m that's not needed.

Stacks usually do not need a tail, just a head. You also never update the tail...

Comment: Thanks for your response. You remind me that the time i studied assembly, POP command in assembly means that clear the content the stack pointer point to.